# WPF Storyboard unable to control new instance of this class, confuse with Silverlight app

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, storyboard, controls

I have a problem with controlling the instance of the class Storyboard.

It's defined in XAML in Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" x:Key="Storyboard1">
```

Also I'm trying to make it stop, like this:

```
        Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)this.TryFindResource("Storyboard1");
        sb.Seek(TimeSpan.Zero);
```

But, no success. If I try to call in your code to the instance Storybord1 then I've got the errors, that there is NO such instance in the current context (and also, if in C# code I try to look with intellisense also no succes, cause of describing pervious problem).

When I'm trying to find this instance with:

```
        foreach (var item in this.Resources)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
        }
```

No success.

I'm not doing smth difficult or using super-encapsulated design pattern, that I can't find/use it.

Just add one UI element and one Storyboard with changing opacity.

I want just to control by myself all Storyboard's play. When I can Stop it and Start it.

In Silverlight I don't get any troubles ( cause Storyboard1 is accessible in Silverlight ), but in WPF all storyboards by defualt are auto-playing and I can't control the its instances.

How can I solve it?

Thank you!

PS
If this can help you with making a piece of advice for me, look:

http://ideone.com/O0x93O - C#

http://ideone.com/Drc1SP - XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I do have access to your storyboard, your Messagebox does popup with the storyboards name. I am presumming that you want your control buttons to fade in when you initiate it in your code behind. I removed the Windows.Trigger that you had to start the Storyboard after that your controls just showed normally, I then set their opacity to 0 and made the Storyboard Instance a class level variable.

```
int count = 0;
Storyboard _sb;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var sb = this.TryFindResource("Storyboard1");
     _sb = sb as Storyboard;
}
```

then using whatever event/condition you want to use to trigger it(*In this case I used the Windows Loaded Event*)

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _sb.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're attempting to do that in the Window Constructor. Move your code to the `Loaded` Event instead.

Comment: Where did you see, that it's in Window Constructor?